# Javascript. Проверить есть ли в блоке фраза, если есть то заменить все предложение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В блоке есть предложение выглядит это так.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="cild1">Какой либо текст для примера</div>
А это тот самый текст, который нужно заменить:
Иван Иванович Иванов - самые частые ФИО, которые встречаются в примерах
   </div>
```

если в блоке `parent` встречается фраза "которые встречаются в примерах", то заменить весь текст в нем на "Измененный текст".
при этом в блоке `cild1` текст менять не должен

Comment: что-нибудь пробовали сами?

Comment: в голову только приходит найти и заменить, но заменится только найденная часть, а как сделать чтобы нашлась только часть а заменилась все пока решения не могу найти. Конечно пробовать буду сам если готового ответа не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Перевод ответа на аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867269/replace-only-text-inside-a-div-using-jquery/11867485#11867485)

Ищите элементы с типом `3` - textNode, а дальше заменяйте их значение

```js
$('.parent').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.indexOf('которые встречаются в примерах') > -1;
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = 'Измененный текст';
});
```

```css
.parent{
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cild1">Какой либо текст для примера</div>
  А это тот самый текст, который нужно заменить: Иван Иванович Иванов - самые частые ФИО, которые встречаются в примерах
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cild1">Какой либо текст для примера</div>
  А это тот самый текст, который нужно заменить: Иван Иванович Иванов - самые частые ФИО
</div>
```

[Подробнее о значениях свойства *nodeType* в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Comment: а тройка - это что?

Comment: это тип - соответствующий textNode.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, добавил ссылку на справку в ответ