# Поиск id элемента по тексту

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно поместить div внутри div c постоянно меняющимся id. Единственное по какому критерию можно найти это текст внутри div. 
Возможно ли получать id элемента по тексту внутри него. 
Пример:

```
<div id="123-dx-fe45">Привет</div>
```

Нужно узнать id div в котором есть слово `Привет`(используя только javascript).

Comment: Можно выбрать все дивы отфильтровать те, внутри которых есть текстовый узел содержащий нужное слово, взять `id`

Comment: [связанный вопрос, с использованием jQuery](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484504/javascript-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/484507#484507)

Comment: Гораздо лучше и проще будет поискать по другим критериям.

Answer (score 1):

```js
~function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]");
  
  for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) {
    if (!divs[q].firstElementChild && divs[q].textContent.match(/Привет/i)) {
      divs[q].className = 'found';
    }
  }
}();
```

```css
.found:after {
  content: " - " attr(id);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="any">
  <div id="1">Привет</div>
  <div id="2">Пока</div>
  <div id="3">И тебе привет</div>
  <div>Привет</div>
</div>
<div id="4">Привет</div>
<div id="5"><span>Привет</span></div>
<div id="6">  Привет  </div>
<div id="7"> Всем привет!  </div>
```

Comment: а чего ты вот такой не считаешь? `<div id="1">Привет, <span>1</span></div>`

Comment: @Grundy, а такой не просили считать, вроде?

Comment: А я вот не уверен, что именно нужно автору :-)

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```js
function getBlocksWithText(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var regexp = new RegExp(text, 'i');
  
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(
    elements, 
    function(el) {
      return el.textContent.search(regexp) !== -1;
    }
  );
}

var elements = getBlocksWithText('div', 'Привет');
var retStr = elements.map(function(el) {
  return el.id
}).join();


alert(retStr);
```

```html
<div id="1">Привет</div>
<div id="2">Пока</div>
<div id="3">И тебе привет</div>
```

Comment: работает не верно в случае если див с текстом будет вложенным, например, если поместить див с id=3, **внутрь** дива с id=2, то в результате выведется `1,2,3`, а не 1,3 как ожидалось

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div:contains("Привет")').attr('id');
```

Comment: при отсутствии меток библиотек, решение ожидается на яваскрипте **без** их использования

Comment: кроме того этот вариант вернет `id` контейнера, а не непосредственно дива в котором расположен текст