# jQuery :contains - затрагивает атрибуты, нужно брать только текст

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, атрибуты

```
for(var word in ExtraWords) {
  $('#page-content *:contains("' + word + '")').html(function(_, html) {
    // if(!$(this).is('[href]') && !$(this).is('[src]')) {
      return html.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), '<span class="highlight-text">' + word + '</span>');
    // }
  });
}
```

Мне необходимо обернуть в тег все слова на странице, которые есть в массиве ExtraWords.
Проблема в том, что мой скрипт "лезет" так же в атрибуты href и src. Почему это происходит - я понимаю, т.к. берется весь html, как текст, затем обрабатывается регуляркой и возвращается. Но я не знаю, как это исправить (пробовал то, что закомментировано - не помогло).

Спасибо!

Comment: а _ExtraWords_ это точно массив? если да, то _word_ будет числовым индексом, а не значением в массиве

Comment: ExtraWords - ассоциативный массив

Comment: то есть объект :-)

Comment: Ну да :) Голова кипит после этой задачи в перемешку с php :)

Comment: У меня еще были data атрибуты и с ними проблемы, часа 4 провел в написании и поисках.

Comment: Возможно тебе поможет ответ на похожий вопрос: [Проверить есть ли в блоке фраза, если есть то заменить все предложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484507/186999)

Comment: ОМГ! :) я думал о нодах, но запутался. То, что нужно, скоро исправлю свой ответ или во имя репутации можешь дать свой - отмечу, как правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: Закрой как дубликат тогда

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку, вроде пометил на закрытие.

Comment: Там у тебя вроде плашка должна была всплыть, с двумя кнопками, если нажать _да, помогло_ должно было сразу закрыться :-)

Comment: Да, было выше :) Я пока ламер на SO :) Спасибо еще раз!